# Connecting to AWS DocumentDB from an AWS ECS Container using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-documentdb

I have a use case where I want to connect and query an AWS DocumentDB cluster from a containerized application deployed in an AWS ECS cluster (Fargate launch-type).

I already have a Task IAM Role defined and I would like to use it for connecting to DocumentDB instead of using a username/password combination.

Is the aforementioned scenario possible to achieve? If yes, how? After reading a lot about the topic, I didn't find a reference on how I can achieve it. Also checked in AWS IAM console the possibility to create a custom Policy, but I didn't find related to DocumentDB actions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears at this time you will have to use username/password authentication to connect to DocumentDB. There is no support at this time for IAM authentication for connections to DocumentDB databases.